# JS - Ooyala API: How do I return this objects title property?

Tags: javascript, api, ooyala

I'm using the Ooyala API (http://www.ooyala.com/support/docs/player_api) to embed videos and want to dynamically change the titles as the videos change.

I've embebbed the video in the html using the following code;

```
   <script src="http://www.ooyala.com/player.js?width=750&height=312&embedCode=dwbjp-XdAc-w6mATLnMIuwBRxHfF5vRK"></script>
```

In the js file, I can then then reload the player by using;

```
document.getElementById('player').setQueryStringParameters({embedCode:'pzcDAxMTrAKV8Y7ClV7VbyLZE6kY4Q8d',autoplay:'1'});
```

As the API provides getCurrentItemTitle, I thought it would as easy as assigning this property to a var and spitting it out again like so;

```
$title = document.getElementById('player').getCurrentItemTitle;
```

.. but, this doesn't seem to work. :(

Anyone any ideas?

Many thanks,

Barry

Comment: That's silly, why do they have all these `getXXX` properties that are named like method names but function like properties? Anyway, what is in the `$title` variable after that line? Anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding parenthesis on the end?

`$title = document.getElementById('player').getCurrentItemTitle();`

Answer (score 0):

doh..of course, it's a function..so needs () appended on the end..just figured it out all on my tod..

Comment: Is this a comment to Jason's answer?